# Application performance and statistics monitor for Unity3d and Flash

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine, performance-testing

I need some performance monitor for my Unity3d and Flash apps (games for example). It must collect stats from user's machines and give me some analitycs like statistics and report builder features/

I want to get some mature MMO performance monitoring solution not to build the whole thing myself. I need to gather values on the server, have some kind of reporting per build, per user configuration and stuff.

The final goal is to be able to record how does my games perform at different hw configurations and be able to track it once the further builds show up. 
I want it to be invisible for the user and hope my problem is I can't guess the right keyword combination to google it.

Hope this makes it more clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is ambiguous, consider revising.  The term "performance" can refer to computer performance(CPU, GPU), user performance in your game (Health, # of enemies killed), or both.  Someone might correct me here but I would suspect such an API doesn't exist because what you track is so very dependent on your game.

Comment: it is about computer performance

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for hardware performance, try:
[Lumos](http://www.uselumos.com/)  It looks like it was designed by [someone in the Unity community](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/90905-Lumos-game-analytics).  I have no direct experience with their package so it might only get you part of the way.

Answer (score 0):

The industry standard for automated performance and testing is [HP's LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1175451#.UFkoXrXA8eU). Based on what you've described this sounds like the perfect solution and as such I would encourage you to take a look at that product. However I must point out that LoadRunner has a steep learning curve and price. Realistically, unless you were a large business it might not be worth the trouble.

You might want to look up alternatives such [Load Storm](http://loadstorm.com/), [webload](http://www.radview.com/product/Execution-environment/Load-generation.aspx) etc... These tools are used by developers to test load stress on servers by using ["virtual machine automatic load generators."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEvSsM40MsI) They generate load on the server and then collect stats based on the current setup that allow developers to make modifications.

Im using LoadRunner as an example just to point you in the right direction (again it's price is crazy... even though its a good tool). Ultimately you will have to pick something that suits your needs but make sure you do your research. I sincerely hope this helps and invite anyone else to expand on this...

Another tool you might want to take a look at is [Bench4q](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/jaspte/). Although it's really a tool for ecommerce I understand that it can be [modified](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/jaspte/Bench4Q-Manual-1.3.0.pdf) to suit your needs which means.

Take care.

Comment: I don't need load performance testing. I want to grab statistics of my users!